# Swapping ng-src attribute using custom service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularjs-scope

I have created a [Pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZgYTGfQ3zDXNXkx7uMc1?p=preview) for you to make it easier. I can make the images swap normaly by writing it in the controller. I was wondering how I can make use of custom services or factories for that matter to implement the same functionality. Here is the code.
**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- navigation bar -->
    <div id="navBar">
        <!-- here goes the dynamic navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- navigation bar ends here -->
    <div class="row fullWidth">
        <!-- sidebar begins -->
        <div id="sidebar" ng-controller="SideCtrl">
            <!-- here goes a static sidebar -->
            <div class="large_3_custom columns">
                <ul class="side-nav side_nav_custom">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/dashboard.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/company_profile.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">COMPANY PROFILE</a>
                        <img ng-click="myData.swapHere();subSec = !subSec" id="arrowRotate" ng-src="{{myData.images.current}}">
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="subSec">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                        <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                    </li>(more on plunker)
```

**Angular**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.service("ReverseService", function() {
    // service func goes here --
    this.imgSwap = function(a, b, def) {
        if (def === a) {
            def = b;
        } else if (def === b) {
            def = a;
        }
    }
})
myApp.controller("SideCtrl", function($scope, ReverseService) {
    console.log("thomas");
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.images = {
        initialImage: "images/prof_arrow1.png",
        finalImage: "images/prof_arrow.png",
        current: "images/prof_arrow1.png"
    };
    $scope.myData.swapHere = function() {
        ReverseService.imgSwap($scope.myData.images.initialImage, $scope.myData.images.finalImage, $scope.myData.images.current);
    };
    $scope.subsec = false;
    $scope.bookSec = false;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do it *not normally*?

Comment: Now it works and I have less crowded controller. My code is more modular after using services. I read somewhere that we need to keep controller logic to the minimum. I was trying to do so. Correct me if this is stupid. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are passing strings into your service function. Strings get unboxed and **not** passed as reference type.

Try passing in the images object into your services function. That should work.

```
myApp.service("ReverseService", function() {
    // service func goes here --
    this.imgSwap = function(images) {
        if (images.current === images.initial) {
            images.current = images.final;
        } else if (images.current === images.final) {
            images.current = images.initial;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I like this idea. However, it is not working for me (no errors). I will keep trying with this idea in mind. Thanks. Here is the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/ONac8RGNplWrMF6aWAsd?p=preview

Comment: Finally made it to work. Changed initial to `initialImage` and final to `finalImage` from your code.